# Interface inherit from other interface in golang

Tags: oop, go

Interface inheritance looks like the following in C#:

```
interface IA{
    void MethodX();
}

interface IB : IA{
    void MethodY();
}
```

How can I reuse interface definition in go?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can embed other interfaces inside an interface, which gives you basicaly the same benefits:

A Good Example is the `ReadWriteCloser` in the io package: 
http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadWriteCloser

It embeds a `Reader`, a `Writer` and a `Closer` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you don't need inheritance,
Golang tests if your struct implements related method in interface so a struct can implement many interfaces

Comment: That's a need for the sake of documentation and cohesion.